# How to load image with same method in both retina/non-retina screen under OS X that's not in the Resources directory?

Tags: macos, cocoa, retina-display

I knew that in [NSImage imageNamed] method, it will try to load retina image on Retina Mac while load non-retina image on Non-Retina Mac, but it was only applied on Resources directory,  is there any other method can do the similar thing on other user-defined directory ?

Answer (score 0):

If the image does not exist in two sizes with one named with the @2x naming convention then you will need to make a best guess judgment call. 
You may also get some useful metadata about the image like DPI to figure out what makes sense.